# Reading from two files at the same time

Tags: java, file

Suppose we have two files as `f1 and f2.`

Also suppose that there is a function named `comparision(File f1,File f2)`. 
This function will get the two files as arguments and take the first character(word) from f1 and compare it with all the characters in the f2 until the end, picking second ones and doing it until end as first and etc.

My question is: How can I implement this? Do I need to know the EOF ? And if so, how to get it?

Assume that files are plain text `(.txt)` and every word is in one line.
as an example:

```
f1:   
I
am
new
to
java

f2:

java 
is
a
programing
language
```

Here's the code:

```
   static void comparision(File f, File g) throws Exception
    {



       Set<String> text = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(g));
for(String line;(line = br.readLine()) != null;)
   text.add(line.trim().toString());
        if(text==null)
            return;


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String keyword = br.readLine();

        if (keyword != null) {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(keyword, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            StringBuffer test = new StringBuffer(text.toString());
            matcher = p.matcher(test);
            if (!matcher.hitEnd()) {
                 total++;
                 if (matcher.find()) {
                     //do sth           
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

edit by jcolebrand

Something to think about, we need program flow that looks like this (psuedocode)

```
function(file1,file2) throws exceptions{
  ArrayList<string> list1, list2; //somebody said we should use an ArrayList ;-)
  string readinTempValue = null;      

  br = BufferedReader(file1) //we are already using a BufferredReader
  readinTempValue = br.ReadLine();

  //this is a loop structure
  while (readinTempValue != null){ //trust me on this one

    //we need to get the string into the array list....
    //how can we ADD the value to list1
    readinTempValue = br.ReadLine(); //trust me on this one
  }


  br = BufferedReader(file2) //we are already using a BufferredReader
  readinTempValue = br.ReadLine();

  //this is a loop structure
  while (readinTempValue != null){ //trust me on this one

    //we need to get the string into the array list....
    //how can we ADD the value to list2
    readinTempValue = br.ReadLine(); //trust me on this one
  }

  foreach(value in list1){
    foreach(value in list2){
      compare value from list 1 to value from list 2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this might be an instructive question for others ... But it needs clarification.  Just posted some edits... can you add the expected output ?

Comment: @user1064929 you're doing fine so far. But you need to break this up into two tasks: read both files in, compare each word in file one to each word in file two. It looks like you're mixing the two together.

Comment: @jcolebrand well my question is how to iterate on second file until it ends?

Comment: @user1064929 if you can read each into a list-type structure at first, then you can use an iterator to go over each of the elements in the list-structure. The simplest form is an array and use index syntax like `foreach (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ //do sth with array[i] }` (but notice that's not good code, that's pseudo code that looks like real code)

Comment: You're already reading in with the bufferedreader, and the string segment for reading in. what you need is an interim place to hold what you're reading in.

Comment: well, i edited my codes again, i used  set<string>, still not working, just read first line then finish :(

Comment: That's because you're not using any loops. You need 3 of them. Loop1 -> Read in file 1. Loop2 -> read in file 2. Loop3 -> compare stuff in file1 to stuff in file2. Try using ArrayList<string> and maybe read in while the read in value is not null. Once it's null, goto the next item to be conquered. (loop2, loop3). I'll update your Q with some notes.

Answer (score 1):

Simple basic algorithm (can be fine tuned based upon WHY you want to compare)

```
Read the second file and create a HashSet "hs"
for each word "w" in file 1
  if(hs.contains(w))
  {
    w is present in the second file
  }
  else
  {
    w is not present in the second file
  }
```

**modifications to OP's code**

```
static int comparision(File f, File g) throws Exception
    {
        int occurences = -1;

        Set<String> text = new HashSet<String>();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(g));
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            String trimmedLine = line.trim();
            if (trimmedLine.length() > 0)
            {
                text.add(trimmedLine.toString());
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        if (text.isEmpty())
        {
            // file 1 doesn't contain any useful data
            return -1;
        }

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String keyword = br.readLine();

        if (keyword != null)
        {
            String trimmedKeyword = keyword.trim();
            if (trimmedKeyword.length() > 0)
            {
                if (text.contains(trimmedKeyword))
                {
                    occurences++;
                }
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        return occurences;
    }
```

Comment: You should explain how to create a hashset. He's already not going to know how to do that. While I know what a hashset is, the OP won't.

Comment: i know how to create a hash set

Comment: but if you dont mind, have a look at my edit, then tell me how to change it to get the answer

Comment: @user1064929 I've updated my post with modifications to your code. You doesn't need PatternMatcher. Also the code isn't following good practices but you get the idea

Comment: Yeah, this might be more complicated without the logic flow. I grok it fine. @user1064929 what you're doing here is using two loops and the nature of a hashset to skip my second loop, so this is using my first loop and third loop, because of the nature of a hashset.

Comment: but in my f1, i got root words, which are the patterns that needed to be looking for them in f2, if i dont use patternmatcher, then how that could happen?and i checed the code you wrote here, because of the reason i mentioned, it returns -1 :(

Comment: @user1064929 what kind of patterns?

Comment: just a simple regular expression

Comment: @user1064929 If the pattern is going to be common across all keywords then you need to create a TreeSet with Custom Comparator that will use  the PatternMatcher.

Comment: I really think pattern matcher is too complex for what's being asked, this is a simple equivalence assignment